# Finding the angle of $-3+5i$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

To find the angle $\theta$ of this complex number I know that I have to imagine it in the complex graph, draw a triangle and then calculate the arctan.

Here is the representation of $-3+5i$ on the graph:

[image]

(I'll explain $\alpha$ and $\phi$ in a moment)

I know that since I have the adjacent and opposite sides of the triangle I can correlate them with the angle using the tangent. Then, I need to calculate the arctan to get the angle.

But my problem is finding the tangent, because I don't know which is the right triangle in this case.

My question is: 
 is $tan \theta = \frac{5}{-3}$ or $tan \theta = \frac{-3}{5}$?

How do I know whether if $\theta$ is supposed to be $\alpha$ or $\phi$?

Comment: $\theta$ is always the angle that the complex number makes with the _positive_ part of the real axis, in counterclockwise direction. So in this case, the angle would, by just immediately guessing, be somewhere in the vincinity of $120^\circ = \frac{2\pi}3$. So it's neither $\alpha$ not $\phi$.

Comment: @Arthur So that would be $\alpha + 90$, in degrees...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it would be.

Comment: It's always arctan of Im(z)/Re(z) as im(x) is always r\*sin (a) and re(z) is always r\*cos(a).  So it's a=arctan (5/-3) = 180 - theta = 90 + alpha.  [arctan (-b) = 180 - arctan b = 90 + arctan (1/b) if restricted to first and second quadrant as your pictures demonstrate.]

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I don't know about the unit circle but I know polar coordinates... The tangent is the slope of the line? Does that mean that if I had a regular graph and drew a circle with it's center on where a linear equation crosses either the x or y axis and calculated the tangent using that circle it would be correct? I had never thought about it that way. Interesting

Comment: Although I prefer thinking of trig in terms of circle, and tan can be the length of tangent from circle to x axis (hence the name), using tan = opp/adj in triangles *never* goes out the door and always stays useful even with polar coordinates.  With polar coordinate a + bi itself goes out the door but in converting.  We they *are* rectangles.  Opposite/adjancent is always more direct than circular tangent lines in my opinion.  But it is *opinion*.  The Great Duck is apparently otherwise.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I'm seeing what problem your viewpoint is attempting to isolate or make easier.  But you do have a point.  tan = slope of radius at the point = rise/run = opposite/adjacent = sin/cos.  It's a good idea to have that "click".  But frankly I find it easier to invent and destroy right triangles instantly in my mind then to work with slopes.  It doesn't go out the door, but it is instantaneous and intuitive.  In my opinion. I guess it's a matter of asking "when you drive a truck up a hill do you see triangles or slope or both"course".

Answer (score 3):

By convention **your** $\theta$ is defined to be

> the angle made with the **positive** $X$-axis in anticlockwise direction

In this case it will be $90^\circ+\alpha$

Answer (score 1):

Angle of complex number is angle the complex vector makes with positive part of real (usually $x$) axis in counterslockwise direction. So, the answer is $\alpha+\frac\pi2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Remember that lengths are positive.**

The green triangle with angle $\varphi$ has an adjacent of length $3$ and an opposite of length $5$.

Hence $\tan \varphi = \frac{5}{3}$ and so $\varphi = \arctan \frac{5}{3} \approx 1.03$.

The red triangle with angle $\alpha$ has an adjacent of length $5$ and an opposite of length $3$.

Hence $\tan \alpha = \frac{3}{5}$ and so $\alpha = \arctan \frac{3}{5} \approx 0.54$.

Notice that $\varphi + \alpha = \arctan \frac{5}{3} + \arctan \frac{3}{5} = \frac{1}{2}\pi$, as expected.

Now, the argument of a complex number is **by definition** the angle made with the positive real axis. So to find the argument of $-3+5\mathrm i$ you stand at the origin looking at the positive reals, e.g. at number $1 = 1+0\mathrm i$. To face the number $-3+5\mathrm i$ you need to turn anti-clockwise to the positive imaginary axis, and then continue on through the angle $\alpha$.

Hence, $\arg(-3+5\mathrm i) = \frac{1}{2}\pi + \alpha = \frac{1}{2}\pi+\arctan\frac{3}{5} \approx 2.11$